# How to tell Mathematica to make assumptions?

Tags: syntax, assumptions

Say I want to integrate `1/(x^2+a^2)` and I want *Mathematica* to know that $a>0$.  What would be the command? Something like:

```
Integrate[1/(x^2+a^2), {x, 0, 1}, {a > 0}]
```

Or, if I want to compute the limit of $\sin(xy)/(xy)$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, $x,y$ reals, what would be the command?

Comment: Check the `Assumptions` options and check the examples in the `Integrate` documentation page.

Comment: Here's from the help file for Integrate: `Integrate[x^n, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> n > 0]`. Maybe the help file would be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

As i know, there should be a command which is `Assuming` as follows,

`Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[1/(x^2+a^2) ,{x,0,1}]]`